If $N$ is odd, is $\sum_{k=1}^{(N-1)/2}\frac{1}{\sin^2(\pi k/N)}$ always rational?
For an odd number of $N$, derive the following
$$\sum_{k=1}^{(N-1)/2}\frac{1}{\sin^2(\pi k/N)}$$
Numerically, it seems to be a rational number, but I can't prove it.

For $N=3$, the answer is $4/3$.
For $N=5$, the answer is $4$.
For $N=7$, the answer is $8$.
For $N=9$, the answer is $40/3$.
For $N=101$, the answer is $1700$.


Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The answer is $\left(N^2-1\right)/6$

Cf. this question

Since J.W. Tanner's link seems to have answered your question, let's close this one as a duplicate, eh? Finite Sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{k\pi}{m}}$
